# mocha: using inject inside beforeEach throws Exception

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have written a test controller which return following object,

```
{hello: 'a', world: 'b'};
```

testing it with mocha following way

```
describe('Test suite', function(){
    let controller;

    beforeEach(window.module('app'));
    beforeEach(function(){
            inject(function($controller){
                controller = $controller('simpleController');
                console.info(controller);
            });
    });

    afterEach(function(){
       console.info("afterEach called");
    });

    describe('Controller', function(){
        it('it should have hello', function(){
            controller.should.have.property('hello')
        });

        it('it should have world', function(){
           controller.should.have.property('world');
        });
    });

});
```

however second test case fails with exception, when inject is called for second time in beforeEach

```
✖ "before each" hook for "it should have world"
      Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.12.1)
    Error: the string "textAngular Error: A unique name is required for a Tool Definition" was thrown, throw an Error :)
```

if otherwise I don't call inject second time, everything works well

```
if (!controller) {
  inject(function($controller){
     controller = $controller('simpleController');
     console.info(controller);
  });
}
```

Ideally I would like a new instance of controller before each test case.

Comment: Of course, a new instance of controller should be created, that's natural. There's nothing in posted code that would cause error. `textAngular Error` obviously came from Textangular. Which likely doesn't do well with re-bootstrapping. Just don't use `app` module where you've got all third-party things in tests. Because they can (and they do) produce side effects.

Comment: @estus removing textAngular solves the issue.